# Cordova application does not resume but restarts after pressing home button and then opening app again

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, android-manifest, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have created an Android application using **Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio CTP 1.1**

The issue occurs when the home button is pressed, the application is sent to the background, and then the app icon is tapped to re-open the app again. Instead of the application resuming, it restarts.

Due to the application being built in **Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio**, there is no way to make any changes to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I also tried adding `<preference name="launchMode" value="singleTask" />` to the `config.xml`, but that did not work.

I am targeting Android 4.1.2

How could I get the application to resume instead of restarting?

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Background Mode plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) will handle this for you in Cordova.

Another approach would be to use the `res/cert` folder to inject content into the native project used to build your app. A custom `AndroidManifest.xml` file can be placed in the res/cert/android folder. The [FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn727288) details this further.

Comment: Thanks Avani, I will try adding a custom AndroidManifest. I will let you know if that resolves my issue.

Comment: Thank you Avani, I have added the AndroidManifest with android:launchMode="singleInstance" and it works like a charm!

Comment: Excellent! Please email vscordovatools@microsoft.com if you have additional questions.